# How to calculate the curvature of a submanifold

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I am learning general relativity, and the geometry is very hard for me.

**The problem:**

Use the Gauss equation to show that the hyperboloid, given by equation $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 - t^2 = -1$ in Minkowski space with metric $-dt^2+dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$ has constant sectional curvature $-1$.

**My progress:**

Let $g_{ab} = \mathrm{diag}(1,1,1,-1)$ be the metric of the Minkowski space, and $h_{ab}$ be the (induced) metric of the 3-submanifold. We can get it with the formula
$$
h_{ab} = g_{ab} + n_a n_b,
$$
where $n$ is a unit normal vector of the 3-submanifold. In our case,
$$n^x = x, n^y = y, n^z = z, n^t = t,\\
n_x = x, n_y = y, n_z = z, n_t = -t.$$
With this, I can write the **4x4** matrix $h_{ab}$.

However, I don't know how to use this 4x4 metric to calculate the curvatures. In my opinion, I need a 3x3 metric to do so.

Comment: Do you know what the second fundamental form is? Have you tried to calculate it?